# Function similar to putenv()

Tags: c

I need some help on creating a function similar to the `putenv()` function of the C standard library, but instead of:

```
int putenv(char *string);
```

it is prototyped as:

```
void env_add(char varname[], char varvalue[]);
```

where `varname[]` and `varvalue[]` are entered by the user and are of type char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should measure the length of `varname` and `varvalue` (with e.g. `strlen`), allocate dynamically a string long enough to hold them, the equal sign and the null terminator, build the `varname=varvalue` string (you can do that with e.g. `snprintf` or `strncat`, or with two `for` loops if you are the masochist type), pass the new string to `putenv` and deallocate the string you've built.

By the way, I'd change the type of `varname` and `varvalue` to `const char *`, because in your function you are not actually modifying them.

Answer (score 0):

That's not very hard:

```
void env_add( char varname[], char varvalue[] )
{
    char* argument = ...;

    /* ...do something to create an argument out of name and value... */

    putenv( argument );
};
```